# What code is getting retrieved from scorecardresearch.com and why? What data is collected?

Tags: support, javascript, tracking

When loading SE sites in the browser is slow, I see `scorecardresearch.com` flashing by in the browser status bar.

The page source shows that `scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js` is retrieved.

What data is collected and why (specifically related to SE sites)?

Their website does not say much:

> ... a leading global market research effort that studies and reports on Internet trends and behavior. ScorecardResearch conducts research by collecting Internet web browsing data and then uses that data to help show how people use the Internet, what they like about it, and what they don’t.

and

> For web tagging, participating websites agree to deploy a special code throughout their sites

Comment: Yes, of course that's a dupe. Why did I not find that when I [searched this site for 'scorecardresearch'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=scorecardresearch) before posting the question?

Comment: @Shog9 Is this *still* being tested, even five years later?

Comment: That's an excellent question, @Jan. [This search works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ascorecardresearch), but [this one doesn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=scorecardresearch) - that seems... wrong.

Comment: @Shog9 Made [a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313892/search-does-not-find-results-when-search-string-in-urls-only) about this