# Search does not find results when search string occurs in URLs only?

Tags: bug, search

From [my question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313685/what-code-is-getting-retrieved-from-scorecardresearch-com-and-why-what-data-is):

If I search for *scorecardresearch* I find my own question but not [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210658/houston-we-are-web-bugged).

That question:

- does not contain the text *scorecardresearch* in the plain question text;
- **does** contain the text in answers.

And:

- [Searching for *url:scorecardresearch*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ascorecardresearch) finds both questions.

Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's a feature! What you've discovered is that the normal search function does not search through urls. This is likely because urls are often long and semi-unrelated to the topic at hand. The reason searching for url:scorecardresearch finds both questions is that both questions contain the url.

Comment: But it also looks like the search algorithm does not visit answers....

Comment: The exact text scorecardresearch is not in the answer in your question, instead it is "scorecardresearch.com". The search algorithm does in fact view answers, such as this search, for example:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=It+might+happen+that+the+"last+activity+indicator"+displays+an+activity+which+is+nowhere+to+be+seen.+This+can+be+the+result+of%3A